# What's more efficient, one big smoke domain, multiple smaller ones, a big adaptive one?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am wondering what's the most optimal practice when implementing smoke.

I have several objects that emit smoke, and these move. Is it better to have one big smoke domain that encapsulates all these objects? or to create a domain for each object -- some would overlap. Also, how could the adaptive option help here?

I see the smoke domain as a bounding box, so if this is a correct analogy, then having a sole big one can lead to a very poor fit. The adaptive option can also leave large empty gaps, since the smoke domain is cubical.

Comment: You can't use multiple domains.

Comment: From my experience multiple is much better, but they shouldn't interact. Otherwise use a big single one.

Comment: Do the smokes interact or not? If yes, you need one big domain. If no, you can bake multiple small domains and re-import them back into the scene.

Comment: They do not need to interact. @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny what do you mean by re-import them back into the scene?

Comment: Ah right, you don't have to, you can just bake each domain individually inside single scene. I usually bake individual simulations (like fires etc.) and then use them in different projects by "importing" them using the external cache option with the file path.

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny I see. I will give that a try